# C# WinForms App won't run on Win7 after Building

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, build

I have a program that I built that reads and writes files. I built it in Release mode, then tried to run the exe on Win7. At first, with troubleshooting on, Windows simply told me the application closed and it was looking for a solution. After a few seconds, the dialog would disappear and show nothing more.

So with some significant effort I got the debugger attached to the process, but it was only showing me disassembly, which tells me that the error taking place wasn't in my application code, but in the framework somewhere.

The strange thing is that when I let the debugger attach, then press "stop" in VS, and exit the debugger, the program actually runs at that point!

So now I'm stumped. I have an application that builds, that seems to be having a permission error when I run it, but if I let the debugger attach then close it, it runs, and there's no Exception to really look at.

How I troubleshoot this issue?

Edit: Responding to Merlyn:

It's a custom app written from scratch in c#. The only dependency it has outside of core .NET namespaces is the Ionic.Zip DLL.

Visual Studio 2008 (Writing in C# 3.5)
Windows 7 - Home Premium, v6.1 build 7600
CPU - x64 quad core
CPU are you compiling under:  Any CPU

I haven't tried it on another machine or a different version of VS.

Edit: I was able to try the compiled version on another win7 computer, and it worked without issue, so it looks like a  security (?) issue on my computer only.

Comment: Have you tried to run the application as an administrator?  Right click on the exe and select the menu option of "Run as administrator".  See if that helps

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Event Log?  It may give more info. (but maybe not if it's compiled in Relase mode.)

Comment: Write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException so you *know* what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes, I did Run as Admin, which enables the debugger to run, but still doesn't run the program properly.

Comment: The even log shows the following error: Faulting application name: DocumentGenerator.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4cd1af70
Faulting module name: MSCOREE.DLL, version: 4.0.31106.0, time stamp: 0x4af3af86
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x0000000000005ab8
Faulting process id: 0x3024
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb7b8d899c33a7
Faulting application path: C:\App\Path\DocumentGenerator.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
Report Id: c74dd080-e780-11df-9fb3-406186c7cfa2

Comment: Also, per your suggestion, I added an event handler to the UnhandledException event, and nothing changed, so I guess it's failing before any part of my app loads?

Comment: Why don't you debug from *within* Visual Studio? It will allow you to step into the program from the start without the hassle of trying to attach to a process that may already be dead.

Comment: When I run it in visual studio it works perfectly, there is no error. It's only after I build the exe and try to run that that this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in the debugger with Just My Code disabled and Native Code enabled, then check the call stack.

Also, what happens if you run it directly in Visual Studio?

Comment: gave it a shot, but no change -- the debugger runs, tells me it can't show disassembly in run mode, then the program launches. I can stop/exit the debugger, and the app continues to run.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Enable Visual Studio Hosting Process in Project Properties and see whether it still works in VS.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest sending the issue to Microsoft support. Especially with the data given here, you will have an easy time convincing them it's their problem. You might need an MSDN subscription for that.

Comment: You *MUST* be kidding here?  Irony?

Comment: -1, A support call at this point is a total waste of time *and* money.  There are way too many variables left that he hasn't even begun to identify, let alone give us parameters for.  If you're being sarcastic, than sarcasm fail :)

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with the support call nooks and crannies of Microsoft. It is that difficult to ask them for support? This was not meant as either sarcasm or a joke.